# Split events into months using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have the a mongodb collection where by all upcoming and past events are in it. However when I fetch the data it does what it should and returns the query as an array which then I turn to JSON (to send to my html iphone app).

What I want to know is there away to split the dates and group each month events in different JSON after I have ran my mongodb query.

here is a sample JSON.

```
{
   "date": "01/11/2013",
   "event": "Event Name",
   "desc": "Sample DESC." 
},{
   "date": "07/12/2013",
   "event": "Event Name",
   "desc": "Sample DESC." 
},
```

in basic terms I want to show the list like

```
November
1: event title
December
7: event title
```

I thought if I split the date, but then I realised that would not help at all it would just split the dates.

I am not asking for someone to code it, I am using for just how to group the dates into different json strings.

It should look like

```
<div>MONTH</div>
<div>EVENT</div>
```

or if multiple events

```
 <div>MONTH</div>
    <div>EVENT</div>
    <div>EVENT</div>
    <div>EVENT</div>
    <div>EVENT</div>
    <div>EVENT</div>
```

This is how I normally edit JSON strings in Javascript.

```
var newsreponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);


    for (var i = 0, len = newsreponse.length; i < len; ++i) {
     var news = newsreponse[i];
     if(i % 2 == 0){
       cssclass = "even";
     }
     else
     {
       cssclass = "odd";
     }

      //  alert(news.featured_image);
     document.getElementById("activecontent").innerHTML += "<div class='news " + cssclass + "'><div class='newstitle'><div class='newstitlecolor'>" + news.post_title + "</div></div><div class='base' style='background: url('" + news.featured_image + "');'><img src='" + news.featured_image + "' style='width:100%; height:100%;'/></div></div>";
    }
```

Comment: Extremely Sorry! but could not understand what you are trying to achieve! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the array and add the values to a new object

```
var raw = [{
   "date": "01/11/2013",
   "event": "Event Name",
   "desc": "Sample DESC." 
},{
   "date": "07/12/2013",
   "event": "Event Name",
   "desc": "Sample DESC." 
}];

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
var ordered = {};

for( var i = 0, len = raw.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var entry = raw[i];
    var m = parseInt(entry.date.split("/")[1])-1;
    if( !ordered[months[m]] ) { ordered[months[m]] = []; }
    ordered[months[m]].push( entry );
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DA8NY/)

Comment: Sorry but while this does put the months and the events under it, I have no way of doing a for loop to call each one, unless I am missing something. as each array starts with the month and maybe my javascript skills just dont know how to do it, I am use to working with the same key when doing a for loop

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What are you trying to accomplish? just print the thing?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to do it. Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DA8NY/2/) with a quick solution

Comment: Is there anyway I can do it by a simple loop, because I want to style and do a few other things I am not seeing how I call each key value in that code, maybe just a lack of skill, Ill post above what I normally do, then you can see where my skill is. sorry about this

Comment: Well, you do it in the same way, you still need an object to keep a reference of which months you have and which you don't, but you can point directly at a dom element rather than an array item.
[Here is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/DA8NY/5/)